# JQUERY COMET for Real-Time multi-user Note Taking

Tags: jquery, comet, collaboration, etherpad

I'm interest in learning how to use jquery comet to create real-time multi-user note taking like etherpad used to offer.

Can anyone offer any tips/tutorials/plug-ins... to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by reading the etherpad source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/) and looking into the [APE project](http://www.ape-project.org/) which is a Comet server that let's you code in javascript. It's very powerful and has a few nice examples.

Comment: So Google purchased Etherpad and open-sourced the code. Awesome

Answer (score 1):

You could use Nginx and JavaScript to implement a Comet based chat system that is very scalable with little memory or CPU utilization.

I have a very simple example here that can get you started. It covers compiling Nginx with the NHPM module and includes code for simple publisher/subscriber roles in jQuery, PHP, and Bash.

http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/2010/08/27/comet-with-nginx-and-jquery/

A working example (simple chat) can be found here:
http://cheetah.jamieisaacs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you saying "JQuery comet". Comet is a technology (or rather technique) that involves both client and server. I've used [Orbited](http://orbited.org/) and it worked quite well for me. It provides complete solution for building comet apps, that is, server with support for many protocols out of the box (I've used STOMP) and JavaScript library to communicate with the server. Check out [this article](http://thingsilearned.com/2009/06/09/starting-out-with-comet-orbited-part-1/) with good introduction on Orbited.